# Why in Batch/DOS (or whatsoever language),REM does make a difference?

Tags: batch-file, dos, batch-processing

Why in Batch/DOS (or whatsoever language), "To avoid this pitfall force CommandBlock2 to succeed, i.e. using a simple REM as last block command: Command1 && (CommandBlock2 & REM) || (CommandBlock3) " could work? 
My question is why adding a remark would change the conditional execution?

Comment: this is taken from here: http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution and is explained pretty well : ` If Command1 fails then CommandBlock2 will be skipped and CommandBlock3 will be executed.
If Command1 succeeds then CommandBlock2 will be executed.
If Command2 fails then CommandBlock3 will also be executed!!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) has given the answer already.

[DOS Tips](https://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) article about **Conditional Execution** explains:

> Be careful when combining the operators, i.e.:
>   **`Command1 && (CommandBlock2) || (CommandBlock3)`**
>
> - If Command1 fails then CommandBlock2 will be skipped and CommandBlock3 will be executed.
> - If Command1 succeeds then CommandBlock2 will be executed.
> - If Command2 fails then CommandBlock3 will also be executed!!
>
> To avoid this pitfall force CommandBlock2 to succeed, i.e. using a simple REM as last block command:
>   **`Command1 && (CommandBlock2 & REM) || (CommandBlock3)`**
>
> or:
>
> **`Command1 && (`**
>      **`CommandBlock2`**
>      **`REM force success`**
>   **`) || (`**
>      **`CommandBlock3`**
>   **`)`**

Comment: Just a note: `REM` does not change `%ERRORLEVEL%`.